# Creating a WiFi Network from an Ethernet Port

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ethernet, wireless-access-point

I'm a student living at a campus community who's WiFi is setup as 802.11x and therefore doesn't support peer-to-peer connections that I require for Airplay, Philips Hue Lights, etc.
However, I have a wired ethernet port to this network in my room from which I'd like to create a regular network which could handle these types of connections.

Since I'm not well versed in this, I'm not sure if I should be looking for an extender, a Wireless Access Point, or simply a plain ole' router. The important thing is that it has ethernet-in and from there outputs its own network. If anyone knows what I should be looking for, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions, depending on your requirements.

**NAT router**

One solution is to connect the Internet port of a wifi-enabled (consumer class) router to the campus Ethernet port in your room. This will create a separate  Wifi network, with a separate IP range, that can be completely managed by you. The router will be using its “NAT” (network address translation) functionality to create your private network.

One advantage of working with your own router and (NATed) network is that, from the “outside world” (campus network), it will only use one IP address and will look like you’ve only connected one device and will offer some (limited) protection.

One disadvantage is that this construction will (depending upon the campus network behind your room’s Ethernet port) probably result in a “Double NAT” network, which will, for most applications, work fine, but might have trouble with some applications.

**Wireless Access Point**

The other solution to your problem is to connect a Wireless Access Point. This will make all devices you connect to it visible on the network behind it (it does not use NAT).

This will not have the disadvantage of creating a “double NATed” network and will give all devices you connect to it an IP address from the campus network.

An alternative to a wireless access point is to connect a consumer router (which are often cheaper and easier to find) to the campus Ethernet connection by one of its (Ethernet) switch ports (and not the Internet port).

*One warning: You might be violating campus policy by connecting a “rogue” network.*